# About interrupt on PIC18F25k50

Tags: c, serial-port, usb

I'm doing a circular buffer for the serial side. Below is the partial coding:

```
void YourHighPriorityISRCode()
{
    if(INTCON3bits.INT2IF == 1)
{
    INTCON3bits.INT2IF = 0; 
}   

if(PIR1bits.RCIF!=1) 
    return;

rxbuf = RCREG;

if (rxbuf==TOKEN)
{
    b485RxToken = 1;
    return;
}   

if (!b485SOH)
{
    if (rxbuf!=SOH)
    {
        return;
    }
    b485SOH=1;
    return;
}   
if (n485RxDataPos>=RS485RXSIZE)
    n485RxDataPos = 0;

RS485RXDATA[n485RxDataPos++] = rxbuf;
if (rxbuf == EOT) 
    b485SOH = 0;    
    }

void main(void)
{
nstate = STATE_RS485_RXDATA;
    while(1)
{
    USBDeviceTasks();
switch (nState)
{

    case STATE_RS485_RXDATA:
        p485 = 0;
        INTCONbits.GIE = 1;
        if (nUSBReady == 0)
        {
            if (n485RxDataPos != n485PrDataPos)
            {
                j = n485PrDataPos;
                for (i=0; i<RS485RXSIZE; i++)
                {
                    if (RS485RXDATA[n485PrDataPos] == EOT)
                    {
                        byTmp = i;
                        n485PrDataPos++;
                        memset (hid_report_in, 0, sizeof(hid_report_in));
                        hid_report_in[0] = SOH;
                        if (RS485RXSIZE - j >= byTmp + 1)
                            memcpy ((void*)&hid_report_in[1], (void*)&RS485RXDATA[j], byTmp);
                        else if (RS485RXSIZE - j < byTmp + 1)
                        {
                            memcpy ((void*)&hid_report_in[1], (void*)&RS485RXDATA[j], byTmp);
                            memcpy ((void*)&hid_report_in[RS485RXSIZE - j + 1], (void*)&RS485RXDATA[0], (byTmp+1)-(RS485RXSIZE - j));
                        }
                        hid_report_in[byTmp+1] = EOT;
                        hid_report_in[byTmp+2] = 0x00;
                        if (RS485RXSIZE - j >= byTmp + 1)
                            memset (&RS485RXDATA[j], 0, byTmp+1);
                        else if (RS485RXSIZE - j < byTmp + 1)
                        {
                            memset (&RS485RXDATA[j], 0, byTmp+1);
                            memset (&RS485RXDATA[0], 0, (byTmp+1)-(RS485RXSIZE - j));
                        }
                        nState = STATE_SERVER_TXDATA;
                        nRS485TX = 1;
                        nUSBReady = 1;
                        break;
                    }
                    n485PrDataPos++;
                    if (n485PrDataPos>=RS485RXSIZE)
                        n485PrDataPos = 0;
                }
            }
        }
                  break;

    case STATE_SERVER_TXDATA:
        if (nHoldTXServer>0)        
        {
            nHoldTXServer--;
            break;
        }
        if (HIDTxHandleBusy(USBInHandle) == 0)       
        {
            USBInHandle = HIDTxPacket(HID_EP, (BYTE*)&hid_report_in, HID_INPUT_REPORT_BYTES);
            nState = STATE_RS485_RXDATA;
            nWaitTXServer = 0;
            nHoldTXServer = nDefaultHoldTXServer;
            if (nRS485TX == 1) 
            {
                nRS485TX = 0;
                nUSBReady = 0;
            }
        }

        if (nWaitTXServer <= 0)
        {
            nWaitTXServer = 5000;
        }
        else
            nWaitTXServer--;

        break;
    }
}
```

The application here is to transmit whatever that is received on serial port through the usb port.
The problem I have here is the device that receive my data from my usb communication sometimes miss out some data. Like if I got four protocol: Protocol A, Protocol B, Protocol C and Protocol D received by the serial port, my usb port is suppose to send out all four protocols also. But the device that received my usb protocol will some times miss one. I want to check what's wrong here.

I have already checked that my serial port got received all four protocols. Now is my usb side. How do I check whether my usb side got send all four out?

I'm using Picket3 so I cannot have a debug windows and printf the data out. The only way I do is to put a breakpoint on the line "USBInHandle = HIDTxPacket(HID_EP, (BYTE*)&hid_report_in, HID_INPUT_REPORT_BYTES);". Whenever my routine run until that breakpoint it will halt. Does by putting a breakpoint at that line shows that my data got transmit out by the usb?

Comment: A lot to review, but I'll toss some ideas.  Using RS-485: are you allowing enough time to turn the I/F around before transmitting? 2) Did not see anything to detect/prevent overfilling the queue in ISR. 3) `(n485RxDataPos != n485PrDataPos)` needs interrupt protection if these vars are wider that native integer size.  `for (i=0; i<RS485RXSIZE; i++) { if (RS485RXDATA[n485PrDataPos] == EOT)` looks scary.  How do you know the EOT you find is not a previous one in the dead space of the queue?   ( i see zeroing out - maybe that's how.)

Comment: 1) Reception of a `SOH` should always begin a message, even if you are in one.  In the latter case, you should dump the partial message. 2) You are not testing for errors (frame, parity, overrun 3) May want to trash partial received message should too long a time occur between bytes.

Comment: Is it that you mean the 'nHoldTXServer'?

Comment: I use "if (n485PrDataPos>=RS485RXSIZE) n485PrDataPos = 0;' to prevent it getting oversize.

Comment: You mentioned 'are you allowing enough time to turn the I/F around before transmitting?' Is it that you mean the 'nHoldTXServer'?

Comment: `if (n485PrDataPos>=RS485RXSIZE) n485PrDataPos = 0;'` is used to wrap -around the circular buffer - not to prevent overfilling.  Say you buf is 100 and you have 90 bytes in the circular queue before `case STATE_RS485_RXDATA` pulls any out.  As `case STATE_RS485_RXDATA` begins to run, 15 more bytes arrive.  The ISR will gleefully write those in the queue, stomping over the first 5 of the previous 90 byte message.  Returning back to `case STATE_RS485_RXDATA`, which is trying to read the 90 bytes which now has a corrupted message.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41646/discussion-between-chux-and-coolguy)